# What different kinds of dragons are there in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've encountered regular dragons of different color and skill, such as ice or fire breath, but I've also encountered Blood Dragons. Are new types appearing as i gain levels? Or does it relate to the main quest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not including story dragons (usually only a single fight, they are named. Can't recall them all):

- Dragon
- Ice Dragon
- Blood Dragaon
- Elder Dragon
- Ancient Dragon
- Serpentine Dragon (DragonBorn DLC)
- Revered Dragon (DawnGuard DLC)
- Legendary Dragon (DawnGuard DLC)

Thats in order of their strengths weakest->strongest. The appear based on your level. Higher level will encounter more elders.
more information on dragons [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons_%28Skyrim%29)

Comment: What level will the elders be seen?

Comment: @knox 40 is their base level